# how to manage reports from cypress run, best management tool options

Tags: cypress

How to manage cypress results after run?, i see a lot of images and videos are captured in the local repo and of course replaced by new results everytime, so how a run results can be managed effectively and for future references.

Also suggest best test run tools, test management tool for all purposes like, build, test, run and look at the results as a dashboard for cypress other than Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [Cypress Dashboard](https://www.cypress.io/dashboard/). Cypress records and automatically uploads test reports from CI as well as local instance there.

Details on how to setup test recording are [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#cypress-run-record-key-lt-record-key-gt)

Comment: yes but all the videos and results are source controlled? meaning can they be stored for future references? what is observed when kickingoff the same test the folder is cleaned up and storing the new results, please clarify.

Comment: I suggest you read into the documentation of it. Also, setup doesn't take longer than 15 minutes really. I'm not sure how for how long will the videos and reports be stored but I can still see all the runs recordings in my project ever since I've started using the service which was 3 months ago.

Comment: i do see them, thanks anyway, however where are they stored?

Comment: Hah no idea really. I guess you have to dive deeper into cypress documentation to find out. Whether they have own storage or use some cloud - I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what you have in place already. For example: we don't store the whole reports of Cypress (there is no use to it, since we are only interested in the things that fail, not the things that work), we only store the failed screenshots/screencasts. Our tests are executed via Jenkins and the screenshots/screencasts are automatically uploaded by Jenkins to a specific page in Confluence.

We had those systems in place and didn't feel the need to buy a license for Cypress Dashboard.

Comment: thanks for comment, may i ask what is the process you have in place to upload results back to Confluence after Jenkins run? i mean are you using any confluence related plugin's for that?

Comment: Indeed, we use Confluence Publisher plugin ( https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Confluence+Publisher+Plugin ) It asks for some configuration and you don't have to do anything else.